# Unable to find an entry point named 'IsTjemePartDefined' in DLL 'uxtheme.dll'

Tags: c#

I'm getting this funky error:

[image]

[image]

It's a simple C# program and it's source is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace SpintaxDecoder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<string> sentences = new List<string>();
        public int Count = 0;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "Generating...";
            button1.Enabled = false;

            Application.DoEvents();

            string data = richTextBox1.Text;

            Random rand = new Random(this.Timestamp());

            for (; ; )
            {
                string spun = this.spintax(rand, data);

                if (sentences.Contains(spun) != true)
                {
                    sentences.Add(spun);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Count++;
                }

                if (this.Count == 1000)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

            label2.Text = this.sentences.Count().ToString();

            foreach (string sentence in sentences)
            {
                richTextBox2.Text += sentence + "\n";
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Completed!", "Information!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            button1.Enabled = true;
            button1.Text = "Start Decoding";

            this.sentences.Clear();
            this.Count = 0;
        }

        public int Timestamp()
        {
            long ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 00:00:00").Ticks;
            ticks /= 10000000;
            return Convert.ToInt32(ticks);
        }

        public string spintax(Random rnd, string str)
        {
            string pattern = "{[^{}]*}";
            Match m = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
            while (m.Success)
            {
                string seg = str.Substring(m.Index + 1, m.Length - 2);
                string[] choices = seg.Split('|');
                str = str.Substring(0, m.Index) + choices[rnd.Next(choices.Length)] + str.Substring(m.Index + m.Length);
                m = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
            }

            return str;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text File|.txt";
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            string file = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (file.Trim() != "")
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);

                string[] lines = richTextBox2.Text.Split('\n');

                foreach(string line in lines)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }

                writer.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("File saved!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/hUjmAvhe

I have no idea how I got this error. 
It has worked well before and now I opened it and I receive this error.

Comment: If you won't paste your issue here, I see no reason to click the link.  But I would bet that `IsTjemePartDefined` is a typo in your code that should be `IsThemePartDefined`.

Comment: You can see the issue on those images.. It doesn't produce any error messages when it compiles.

Comment: `Find all "IsTjemePartDefined", Subfolders, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, ""
  Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 10
` It can't find that kind of matching word from my solution

Comment: Thanks, that find result is useful.  Sorry I was so harsh, but it's inconvenient to open up 2 extra windows to try to help you solve your problems - as well as being bad practice, because those links can become invalidated, and this question then becomes useless for others.  Regarding your problem, there is no "IsTjemePartDefined" anywhere in google other than right here, but there is an MS function `IsThemePartDefined`.  If it's not in your code, then this looks bad.  To me, it implies that one of your underlying libraries is corrupted, though I hope someone else can give you a nicer answer.

Comment: Yes that's very weird. Also some thing happened to me when I tried to use another .NET program (not made by me) in my server. It threw errors like this. Maybe it's a virus or something ?

Comment: Virus is possible, and it wouldn't hurt to check.  It's usually hard for a .NET library to be corrupted and still be usable.  They're usually signed and checksummed.  You may be looking at a reinstall of your .NET framework, and/or of Visual Studio.  The easiest step is to find a clean uxtheme.dll, replace it and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll run virus scans on both - my PC and my server. I'll see how it goes. I'll report when I have fixed this problem.

Comment: Okay I was able to fix this problem by reinstalling .NET 4.5 and it appears it's working well now. That program's design is fine and runs fine too. I believe it was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Heh, one of the ~8 trillion bits on machine's disk drive flipped from a 0 to a 1.  Probably not the only one.  That this didn't generate a CRC error is very unhealthy.  Then again, maybe it did and it auto-recovered, rescuing whatever data it could still read.  Ought to be something about it in the Windows event logs.

Replacing it should be very high on the list of recommended counter-measures.